# deploying two EARs in a single weblogic server

Tags: jar, weblogic, ear

I am trying to migrate an application on a Weblogic server which already has an application in it. Please suggest if having two EARs in the same weblogic server is a feasible design

Comment: ok. then how can the two .ears communicate internally?

Comment: You didn't mention that! Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: That's another question, but look for techniques such as web services (soap & rest) and rmi (ejb remote)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly feasible and standard; however, there are one or two reasons why you might not want to do this.

One is file descriptor exhaustion. If one of the applications (EARs) runs out of file descriptors, it will probably crash / render inoperable the entire process, i.e. the entire Weblogic server.

Another is heap memory exhaustion; much the same problem occurs if one of the applications exhausts the maximum available heap memory.

Application servers try to isolate applications from each other, but cannot completely succeed at this due to the limitations of the JVM. Operating systems and virtual machine hypervisors are actually able to do a better job of isolating applications from each other.